# Server Directory Not Accessible

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got strange things happen on live server, but normal in local server.
My local server is using mac, and my live server is linux.

Consider i try to access some files
`http://redddor.babonmultimedia.com/assets/images/map-1.jpg` This work correctly.
`http://redddor.babonmultimedia.com/assets/modules/evogallery/check.php` Return 404, I'm pretty sure my file is in there and there is no typo mistake.

**How come it give me 404?**

There is only one .htaccess on the root server and it's configuration is like this.

```
# For full documentation and other suggested options, please see
# http://svn.modxcms.com/docs/display/MODx096/Friendly+URL+Solutions
# including for unexpected logouts in multi-server/cloud environments
# and especially for the first three commented out rules

#php_flag register_globals Off
#AddDefaultCharset utf-8
#php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Reduce server overhead by enabling output compression if supported.
#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Comment: I'm refunding your bounty on this one as you've solved it yourself. No point in throwing away good rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of CHMOD, in some server we not allowed to have 777 for folder, it should be 755.
Change all folder CHMOD into 755 and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This rule here:

```
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
```

Needs to look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/ - [L]
```

Your regex is **only** matching the URI's `/manager/` and `/assets/`, and not something like `/assets/modules/evogallery/check.php` because the `/*$` at the end means no more directories, only slashes. The image URL worked because the rule after this one excludes all images.

Comment: I try your suggest, but still get 404.